# Why is this do-while loop in infinite?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, do-while

I am learning the do-while loop and am unable to understand why this loop is running infinitely.

```
 var condition = true

 var getToDaChoppa = function(){

      do {
          console.log("I'm the do loop");
      } while(condition === true){
          console.log("I'm the while loop");
          condition = false;
      };

    };

 getToDaChoppa();
```

Comment: The loop starts with the `do` and ends with the `while`, and nothing in between changes the `condition`. The block after it is just a separate block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never set the `condition` variable to `false` **INSIDE** the loop, so it will never execute any of your code outside of the loop until this loop has completed (which will never happen given your current example). Make sure that you set the `condition` variable to `false` inside the loop:

```
do {
    console.log("I'm the do loop");

    if (some_condition_is_met) {
        condition = false;
    }
} while(condition === true);
```

Comment: HI Darin, I just realised the mistake! Can you give the improved answer and I will accept the answer for users in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Do/While works like this. So you never change the `condition` inside the loop.

```
do {
    //code block to be executed
}
while (condition);

//Code after do/while
```

Comment: So what does the the bit in the 'while' loop do? Is it there to check if the condition has been met?

Comment: You can basically do anything inside there.Manage a counter or something like that. You just need to make sure that sooner or later the `condition` gets set to `false` or otherwise it will never end.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `do..while` and there is a `while..`: *there is no `do..while..` statement*.

JavaScript allows [block statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) independent of other flow-control/definition constructs. Due to lack-of-a-required statement semicolon this does not result in a syntax error (it would in Java).

Here is some additional clarification relating to the *syntax*; other answers cover the logical error.

```
do {
    console.log("I'm the do loop");
} while(condition === true) // semicolons optional in JS (see ASI):
                            // 'do..while' statement ENDS HERE
{  // starts a block statement which has naught to do with 'do..while' above
   // THERE IS NO WHILE LOOP HERE
    console.log("I'm the while loop");
    condition = false;
}; // useless semicolon which further leads to confusion
```

On the other hand, if the `do..` was omitted it would have been parsed as "just" a `while` statement which would have terminated.

```
// Basic WHILE statement - no 'do..' code, so NOT parsed as a 'do..while'!
while(condition === true)
{  // this block is now part of the 'while' statement loop
    console.log("I'm the while loop");
    condition = false;
};
```